# Deriving relationships between nodes of different graphs

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a requirement to load multiple graphs in the database. These are not connected to each other. Once the graphs are loaded, we want to create relationship between the nodes on the various graphs if they have at least one property with the same value. Is there is any algorithm available for this efficiently?

Comment: Have you a list of know properties or each node can have random properties?

Comment: Each node can have random properties. We do not enforce a schema, so users can bring their own data and upload the data using their own properties and labels...